# How to see content place holder's content in default.aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

This problem may be a bug. i have spent too much time trying to solve it.

I inherited a master page to mycustom aspx pages but I can not see the aspx page content. (maybe my visual studio  does not detect contentplace holder).

My master.aspx :

RESULT : This page inherited from Site.Master but I can not see contents
[image]

Why can I not see my content areas inherited page from master page? How would this issue be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style=" background-color:Silver; background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;  width:64%;" visible="false" >
```

i think its because your div is hidden =)

Answer (score 1):

Penguen, can't you see the content when you enter in the 'design view' or when you are running the app?

Comment: if i click design View, i can not add new control. page closed

Answer (score 1):

Your ContentPlaceHolder `ContentPlaceHolder1` is nested inside the `PlaceHolder` control with ID=plhToolBar on the Master page.  I think it needs to be directly on the Master page, not nested inside another control.